# Accessing Magento search results collection

Tags: magento, search

I need to get a list of the `skus` returned by the `Magento` search results. I've looked around and googled but cannot find where the products come from when displaying them on the search results page. I have the `searchresults.phtml` file open. It looks like when `$this->getChildHtml('content')` is called that is where the products are looped through but I think there is some magic going on with the core/textlist. Anyway I'd like to access the product collection provided by the search results and loop through it on the searchresults.phtml file.

EDIT: Just to clarify, what I really need is access to the product collection that comes from the search results.

EDIT: Turns out that searchresults.phtml is a custom page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After realizing I was working with a custom template I now see there are probably two places I'll need to address:

catalogsearch/result.phtml

catalogsearch/advanced/result.phtml

For result.phtml the block is Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Result. In that block you can call `$this->_productCollection()`. The sku is in the collection. I'm assuming the same is true for advanced.

EDIT: for the advanced search you have to use `$this->getChild('search_result_list')->_productCollection`.

Answer (score 2):

in app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/catalog/product/list.phtml
there is a line:

```
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
```

If you want to get ALL skus (not limited per page) inside that template you can do:

```
$select = clone $_productCollection->getSelect();
$select
        ->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_COUNT)//remove this line if you want list of skus belonging only to current page
        ->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_OFFSET) // and this one too
        ->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
        ->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER)
        ->columns('sku');
$all_skus = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read')->fetchCol($select,'');
```

Answer (score 0):

**catalog Search**

extend below class

```
\app\code\core\Mage\CatalogSearch\Block\Advanced\Result.php
```

create new function in result.php

```
protected function skuProductCollection(){
        return $this->getSearchModel()->getProductCollection()->getColumnValues('sku');
    }
```

and write below code in your phtml file

```
<?php $allSku = $this->skuProductCollection() ?>
<?php print_r($allSku); ?>
```

hope this will help you

Comment: I need to access the product collection in the searchresults.phtml file.

Answer (score 0):

Inject in the constructor of your class:

```
\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Search $collectionProducts
```

And then you can retrieve search results collection, exactly the same as on search page:

```
$collection = $this->collectionProducts->getProductCollection();
```